# Flutter - load data async inside initState

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, state

Just after new page is created, I need to load webservice data (while loading is in progress, busy inducator should be displayed), then when loading done, show data.

My approach is load data inside `initState` override, this way:

```
void initState() {
    
      setState(() => _isLoading = true);
      fetchData().then((value) {

       // Do something with data
       widget.value = value;

        setState(() => _isLoading = false);
      });
    }

    super.initState();
  }
```

Then, build method will display either loading indicator, or loaded data depend from `_isLoading` value.

For now, it works but I don't feel it's good way, especially afaik, `setState` call should be avoided inside `initState`.

Can you provide any tips how to do the same better, without complicating code too much? Or, my approach is acceptable in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `FutureBuilder` to build the Widgets?
You'll then be able to deal with the 'loading' state too.

Example:

```dart
return FutureBuilder(
    future: yourAsyncCall,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return MaybeProgressBar();
      else return TheWidgetYouMade();
    }
});
```

Comment: FutureBuilder is correct but make sure that `yourAsyncCall` is made in the `initState` method, store the result in the state and pass it to the FutureBuilder. Read the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) carefully

Comment: Good solution, I forgot about `FutureBuilder`